# nextjs 14 Error 401 when requesting data from middleware in production

Tags: node.js, next.js, middleware, next.js13, app-router

Everything works fine in development, but **on the server the request gives a 401 error**. The URL is correct and functional, but for some reason nextjs seems to block the request.

The code:

```js
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const endpoint = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST + '/api/some-data'
  const data = await fetch(endpoint,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      cache: 'no-store'
    }
  ).then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${res.status}\nAt route ${endpoint}`);
    }
    return res.json()
  })

  //...

  return NextResponse.next()
}
```

**nextjs version**: 14.0.3

I'm using app router if relevant.